# How to sum rows before a condition is met in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table which has multiple records for the same id. Looks like this, and the rows are sorted by sequence number.

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | result | duration | sequence |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 12     | 7254     | 1        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 12     | 2333     | 2        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 11     | 1000     | 3        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 6      | 5        | 4        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 1  | 3      | 20       | 5        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 1      | 230      | 1        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 9      | 10       | 2        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 6      | 0        | 3        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 1      | 5        | 4        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| 2  | 12     | 3        | 5        |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

E.g. for `id=1`, i would like to sum the duration for all the rows before and include `result=6`, which is `7254+2333+1000+5`. Same for `id =2`, it would be `230+10+0`. Anything after the row where `result=6` will be left out.

My expected output:

```
+----+----------+
| id | duration |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 10592    |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 240      |
+----+----------+
```

The sequence has to be in ascending order.

I'm not sure how I can do this in sql.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you are expecting one record in the resultset for each `id`, meaning your sample data would yield two records (one for id `1`, with value `7254+2333+1000+5`, and the other for id `2`, with value `230+10+0`) ?

Comment: @GMB yes that what i meant, let me put my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t2.id, sum(t2.duration)
from t
where t.sequence <= (select t2.sequence
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id and t2.result = 6
                    );
```

In PrestoDB, I would recommend window functions:

```
select id, sum(duration)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when result = 6 then sequence end) over (partition by id) as sequence_6
      from t
     ) t
where sequence <= sequence_6;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple aggregate query with a condition that uses a subquery to recover the `sequence` corresponding to the record whose sequence is `6` :

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(t.duration) total_duration
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.sequence <= (
    SELECT sequence
    FROM mytable
    WHERE id = t.id AND result = 6
)
GROUP BY t.id
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ECaSBD75nNGQ7gMfw4B9h/2)** with your test data returns :

```
| id  | total_duration |
| --- | -------------- |
| 1   | 10592          |
| 2   | 240            |
```

Comment: Yes compute sum but not "except the one corresponding to the latest sequence", there might be more records after "result = 6", so I want everything before the row where "result =6" for all ids

Answer (score 0):

Basic group by query should solve your issue

```
select 
  id,
  sum(duration) duration
from t
group by id
```

for the certain rows:

```
select 
  id,
  sum(duration) duration
from t
where id = 1
group by id
```

if you want to include it in your result set

```
select id, duration, sequence from t 
union all
select 
  id,
  sum(duration) duration
  null sequence
from t
group by id
```

Comment: This is not working because I only want certain rows not all of them.

Comment: check my answer again please